# What happened to Rhaegar Frey?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In [ADWD chapter 19](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons-Chapter_19), we see an envoy from house Frey that includes Rhaegar Frey, returning the bones of one of Lord Wyman Manderly's sons. But he never makes it to the

> wedding of fake Arya at Winterfell.

What happened to him and his companions?

Comment: Are you *sure* he doesn't make it to the wedding? ;) (I don't think it's explicitly written in the text, but there are fan theories...)

Comment: The north remembers.

Comment: Here is the theory summed up: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Frey_Pies/Theories Don't read it unless you want the mystery spoiled, needless to say.

Comment: In addition to that summary, I seem to recall someone making a specific point about Wyman Manderly using the word "Mayhaps" several times, which is apparently a thing Freys do when they lie.

Comment: @TLP - Sounds like you almost have an answer there :)

Comment: @JustinEthier All right, here's an answer. :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As copied from the theory section of the wikipedia at Westeros.org, the Theory of [the Frey Pies](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Frey_Pies/Theories)

-- start --

> *The best pie you have ever tasted, my lords. Wash it down with Arbor gold and savor every bite. I know I shall.*
>
> -- Wyman Manderly during the wedding of fake "Arya Stark"

The Frey Pies Theory is that Wyman Manderly killed the three Freys (Rhaegar, Symond, and Jared) who disappeared on the way from White Harbor to Winterfell and baked them into the three huge meat pies he brought for Ramsay Bolton's wedding at Winterfell.
Supporting Evidence

- Lord Wyman suggests to Davos Seaworth he means to have all three Freys murdered and intimates about giving a guest gift to the Freys in line with their house's breach of guest right at the Red Wedding.
- Roose Bolton suspects Lord Wyman had the Freys killed while on the road from White Harbor to Winterfell. Lord Wyman insists the Freys travelled ahead of his column out of impatience over Wyman's slow pace. While not implausible, this is a very flimsy story.
- Lord Wyman presents 3 huge pies at the wedding, one for each of the missing Freys.
- When the pies are served at the wedding, Lord Wyman cuts portions personally for the Boltons and Freys, to ensure they would eat it. He serves them with great (drunken) exuberance.
- At the wedding, Lord Wyman has Abel the Bard sing the Rat Cook for them, a song about an evil cook who kills a prince and bakes him into a pie he then serves to the king. Shortly after Bran dreamed Robb's death, he reflected on the legend of the Rat Cook: he was transformed into a giant white rat by the gods, not because of his deeds, but specifically because he dishonoured guest right.

-- end copy --

I have also heard it mentioned that during this feast and the questioning about the missing Freys, Lord Wyman said "mayhaps" several times. The use of the word "mayhaps" is a part of a children's game the Freys play (the lord of the crossing) where you are allowed to lie, as long as you include the word "mayhaps" in what you say.

The evidence is not overwhelming, but when you read the book with this in mind, it becomes rather more apparent that this is what happened, in my opinion. Especially considering the anger Lord Wyman shows when talking to Davos.

> "They watch me, ser. Day and night their eyes are on me, noses sniffing for some whiff of treachery. You saw them, the arrogant Ser Jared and his nephew Rhaegar, that smirking worm who wears a dragon's name. Behind them both stands Symond, clinking coins. That one has bought and paid for several of my servants and two of my knights. One of his wife's handmaids has found her way into the bed of my own fool. If Stannis wonders that my letters say so little, it is because I dare not even trust my maester. Theomore is all head and no heart. You heard him in my hall. Maesters are supposed to put aside old loyalties when they don their chains, but I cannot forget that Theomore was born a Lannister of Lannisport and claims some distant kinship to the Lannisters of Castlerly Rock. Foes and false friends are all around me, Lord Davos. They infest my city like roaches, and at night I feel them crawling over me." The fat man's fingers coiled into a fist, and all his chins trembled. "My son Wendel came to the Twins a guest. He ate Lord Walder's bread and salt, and hung his sword upon the wall to feast with friends. And they murdered him. *Murdered*, I say, and may the Freys choke upon their fables. I drink with Jared, jape with Symond, promise Rhaegar the hand of my own beloved granddaughter... but never think that means I have forgotten. **The north remembers, Lord Davos. The north remembers, and the mummer's farce is almost done.** My son is home."
>       Something about the way Lord Wyman said that chilled Davos to the bone.

And later:

> My body has become a prison more dire than the Wolf's Den. Even so, I must go to Winterfell. Roose Bolton wants me on my knees, and beneath the velvet courtesy he shows the iron mail. I shall go by barge and litter, attended by a hundred knights and my good friends from the Twins. The Freys came here by sea. They have no horses with them, so I shall present each of them with a palfrey as a guest gift. Do hosts still give guest gifts in the south?"
>       "Some do, my lord. On the day their guest departs."
>       "Perhaps you understand, then."

Quotes from *A Dance with Dragons*, pages 389, 392, Davos IV.

Comment: It is easy to see that even though padded with excess words, the core GRRM style and feel is still strong in ADWD.

Comment: +1 - Great answer. Although he only seems to say mayhaps once or twice, good catch with the connection: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_of_the_crossing

Comment: @JustinEthier I remember him saying it when they had discovered the dead Walder Frey: `Mayhaps it was a blessing. Had he grown up, he would have become a Frey.` (paraphrasing from memory).

Comment: Yup, that's the one. Great quote :)

Comment: I had always considered the Frey pies to be fact. Didn't realize people still regard it as a theory. It's one of the many things in ADWD that's propelled Lord Manderly from the fat oaf he was portrayed as earlier into a badass worthy to be called a true Northener. All of House Manderly really.